# signalR freezes UI when the client is idle

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, signalr

I have a problem with the main application window freezing. I start communication with the signalR server, then when I minimize the main window and don't open it for a while, it hangs.

```
    public static NotificationServerProxy GetNotificationServerProxy(string notificationServerURI, User user, Dispatcher dispatcher = null)
    {
        NotificationServerProxy nsp = new NotificationServerProxy
        {
            dispatcher = dispatcher ?? System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher
        };
        User = user;
        canRegisterClientMethods = nsp.Connect2(notificationServerURI, hubName).Result;
        return nsp;
    }
```

The problem can also be replicated by connecting via TeamViewer to the station. All I need to do is launch the main application window, disconnect from TeamViewer, reconnect after a few seconds and the main window hangs

```
    public async Task<bool> Connect2(string notificationServerURI, string hubName)
    {
        {
            WriteExceptionToLog($"{logPrefix}, notificationServer.IsNotConnected");
            try
            {
                
                WriteExceptionToLog($"{logPrefix}, BEFORE CreateConnected() serverURI = {notificationServerURI}, hubName = {hubName}");
                
                hubConnection = new HubConnection(notificationServerURI);
                hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                hubConnection.StateChanged += OnConnectionStateChanged;
                hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);

                WriteExceptionToLog($"{logPrefix}, AFTER CreateConnected()");
                
                await StartConnectionAsync();
                
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteExceptionToLog($"{logPrefix}, ERROR IN StartConnection(): {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        WriteExceptionToLog($"{logPrefix}, NotificationServerConnect() END");
        return false;
    }

    private async Task StartConnectionAsync()
    {
        await hubConnection.Start();
    }
```

Comment: `async void` is almost always a bug. It should only be used for asynchronous event handlers. `StartConnectionAsync` isn't an even handler. Your code returns `true` before the hub connection had a chance to start. Change the return type to `async Task`, use `await StartConnectionAsync();`,  change `Connect2`'s return type to `async Task<bool>` and await that as well

Comment: When you use `async/await` you don't need to marshal calls to the UI thread. Which makes the `dispatcher` property suspicious. I suspect the rest of the code actually blocks the UI thread because there's no active SingalR connection. This has little to do with SignalR

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It looks like the app is not fully loading at this time. Part of the UI loads, and freezes after a while. I edited the main post with the code comments you made, for which I thank you in advance

Comment: now you need to call ``nsp.Connect2(notificationServerURI, hubName).Result;` with await in `GetNotificationServerProxy` and make that functions also async. Did you test the changes PanagiotisKanavos recommended?
The freezing is because your application is blocked by waiting for SignalR, so you need to call this in an async way.

Comment: Everything works like a charm now. Thank you very much for your help. Now I understand that this is not a problem with signalR